# c# format textboxes to currency when they lose focus

Tags: c#, winforms

I have several lists of text boxes on a form each representing a column of a database. I want to update the form each time the user exits one of the boxes for price. the name of this list is priceBox[]. I am aware of the lostFocus event but I cant seem to figure a way to get it to work for a collection and this list can grow so I cant have a fixed number. I dont have any code for this yet. if it helps the text box controls are contained in a panel named panel1.

I have tried searching and cant find anything on this. only for singular instances, like updating 1 text box.

sorry if this is a duplicate but I did try to search. also I am new to c#.

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is adding a ControlAdded handler to the panel, so every time a new textbox is added, it automatically adds LostFocus handler for it. Step-by-step below:

For your panel you bind a handler ControlAdded event, which would be something like:

```
private void Panel1_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
{
    var tb = e.Control as TextBox;
    if (tb != null)
    {
        tb.LostFocus += new EventHandler(TextBox_LostFocus);
    }
}
```

Then in TextBox_LostFocus you can add whatever logic you want

```
void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tb = sender as TextBox;
    if (tb != null)
    {
        // modify tb.Text here, possibly like this...
        tb.Text = String.Format("{0:C}", Decimal.Parse(tb.Text));
    }
}
```

To update all existing controls (not tested)

```
foreach (TextBox in panel1.Controls)
{
    tb.LostFocus += new EventHandler(TextBox_LostFocus);
}
```

Comment: i am trying this now as it seems like a great approach but I am having a brain fart or something and I cant think of how to check the control  to make sure it is a textbox.

Comment: that is great thanks! but it never fires the event. is this only going to create the event for new controls? what about the ones that exist when the app starts? I can add those manually i guess but I would really like a more dynamic solution. nm i added them in and it does. I got it to fire now but it doesnt format it. I will figure that one out. thanks again.

Comment: @JohnS You can do a foreach of the Forms Control collection after you InitializeComponent Method in your Constructor and add your Common Event at that time, Also to check for TextBox you can use something like this, `if (object.ReferenceEquals(e.Control.GetType(),typeof(TextBox)))`

Comment: Added extra for binding events to all existing textboxes, you'll have to figure out where to call that code though, possibly when the form is loaded. Modifying text inside LostFocus definitely works, I just wasn't sure what currency format you were after, so didn't add anything yet.

Comment: @MikeTrusov I was using `string.Format("{0:c}", tb.Text)` to get it to format to currency. didnt work though

Comment: I think you have to parse it into decimal before it can be formatted as currency